# How can I print all of this webpage into a PDF file in FireFox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf, printing

I would like to print the following webpage into a PDF file :

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#2

But in FireFox or chrome browsers, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> can only print first half part of the webpage. If I scroll it down, I can only print the lower half of the webpage. What can I do to print all of the webpage?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "partial"?

Answer (score 0):

I have Google Chrome and I can print into a pdf the entire page you mentioned in the link.

Later edit: or you can try [this](https://webpagetopdf.com/)

Later edit 2: example of saving entire pdf:

[image: picture]

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Can you show the "entire" page in a pdf file? I hope your pdf file doesn't miss the end of the webpage which contains `sudo service smbd restart`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: A pdf file for the "entire" page beginning from "3. Setting up Samba" to "sudo service smbd restart "

Comment: See my update....

Comment: I understand what you mean. I simply press CTRL+P, choose to print as pdf, as I showed.